# Google site, add common Google Apps script project to be called by other projects

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classic-sites

I have created a Google site, in manage site there is option to add Google apps script and I can add multiple Google Apps Script projects that can be embedded in Google Site. Please see below screenshot:

[image]

In this image, you can see four projects. Is it possible to add a common project that has common functions used by all four projects? So basically the four projects will make calls to the functions in files of the common project.

I have gone through Google API documentation and can't seem to find anything unless I have missed it.

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle a "common project that has common functions used by" other projects is through the library feature.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

> A library is a project whose functions can be reused in other scripts. To learn how to properly create, include, and use a library, see the sections below.